# How to send parameter with a 'on' listener?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am not able to send a parameter with `on` listener. Here is my code:

```
$.each(this.elements, function(i,element){
            
        var tagName = $(element).prop('type').toUpperCase();
        
        switch(tagName) {
            case "TEXT" :
            case "TEXTAREA" :
                $(element).on('focus input focusout', that.inputHandler, tagName); //not working
            case "SELECT-ONE" : 
                $(element).on('change focusout', tagName, that.selectHandler); //not working
            case "RADIO"      :
            case "CHECKBOX"   :
                $(element).on('change focusout', tagName, that.changeHandler);
        }
        
    });
```

Example :

```
this.inputHandler = function (e,tagname) {
          console.log(e,tagname); //i am getting error. how to fix this?
        var val =  $(this).val();
        this.errorHandler(val);
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me the right way please?

Comment: declare `var self = this` to memorise the scope reference?

Comment: you haven't defined "that"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the tagName is a string, in such case jQuery will assume it to be a delegated event handler instead of interpreting it as data. so try

```
$(element).on('change focusout', {tagName:tagName}, that.changeHandler);
```

then you can access the tagName from the event object like

```
event.data.tagName
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/358sV/)

Answer (score 0):

> **handler**
>     Type: Function( Event eventObject )
>     A function to execute when the event is triggered.
>
> When the browser triggers an event or other JavaScript calls jQuery's .trigger() method, **jQuery passes the handler an *event object***, it can use to analyze and change the status of the event.

As the document has presented, you can't pass self-defined data to the handler. But as the `on` document presents,

`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`

you can pass self-defined data by this way( official example ):

```
function myHandler( event ) {
    alert( event.data.foo );
}
$(element).on( "click", { foo : "self-define-data" }, myHandler );
```

Most of the time, read the official document would be more helpful.

Comment: appears same as @ArunPJohny answer to me....except that you changed `tagName` to `foo` ;)

Comment: Sometimes, I thinks konwing why also matters.